# Responsive website on nokia lumia 920

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a website which I created with the help of bootstrap and my issue is when I view my website on my 920 it appears to be rendering 768px which is my tablet break point which has the full navigation links and mobile break point has the navigation hidden. I know the 920 has a resolution of 768x1280 but I am a little confused as to how the width is 768 and what do I do to get things sorted. Any other media query needs to be added?

Comment: I am sorry, but you just said the resolution is 768px wide. So what else do you expect to render but whats supposingly meant to be rendered for 768px.

Comment: "but I am a little confused as to how the width is 768". Width is 768 pixels because on the newer phones they are packing more pixels per inch now a days.

Comment: It is a mobile device and I expect the navigation to be hidden and when I click on the button it should slide down as it is intended to do so. I have tested on my brothers 820 and it works fine as his resolution is 400x800 so it is taking the default break point of bootstrap for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would get help from here but then I should have researched a bit. Anyways I have found a fix for this. There is an article written on http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html and it does fix the issue for me. There are still a few issues that can get sorted with media query. I will solve those and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with min-resolution(dpi) in your media query, i think the lumia 920 is 192dpi

Comment: The 920 is 332dpi and this issue cannot get sorted with media query as the navigation is by default mobile first.